# AngularJS $lcoation.search() - Make case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-parameters

I'm using the AngularJS `$location.search()` function to retrieve url params, and I was hoping that there was an easy way to make this case insensitive. With the research I have made, I haven't been able to find any solutions.

Consider the following:

`http://mytestapp.com/signup?type=development`

Here's my code:

```
var type = $location.search().type
console.log(type);
```

Using the url from above, the output is `development`
Using this url (`http://mytestapp.com/signup?Type=development`) the output is `undefined` (notice the `Type` letters).

How can I make the function case insensitive?